# Dynamically add javascript script to page with code not src

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out how to inject this script into a site using Tampermonkey. Here is what I have so far but the onBrazeSdkLoaded event is never being called so I don't think its being inserted correctly. I have tried a few iterations but no luck. To reference the exact script I am trying to include here is the link to the public docs.

https://www.braze.com/docs/developer_guide/platform_integration_guides/web/initial_sdk_setup/#install-gtm

```
const script = document.createElement("script");
        var code = document.createTextNode(`+function(a,p,P,b,y){a.braze={};a.brazeQueue=[];for(var s="BrazeSdkMetadata DeviceProperties Card Card.prototype.dismissCard Card.prototype.removeAllSubscriptions Card.prototype.removeSubscription Card.prototype.subscribeToClickedEvent Card.prototype.subscribeToDismissedEvent Card.fromContentCardsJson Banner CaptionedImage ClassicCard ControlCard ContentCards ContentCards.prototype.getUnviewedCardCount Feed Feed.prototype.getUnreadCardCount ControlMessage InAppMessage InAppMessage.SlideFrom InAppMessage.ClickAction InAppMessage.DismissType InAppMessage.OpenTarget InAppMessage.ImageStyle InAppMessage.Orientation InAppMessage.TextAlignment InAppMessage.CropType InAppMessage.prototype.closeMessage InAppMessage.prototype.removeAllSubscriptions InAppMessage.prototype.removeSubscription InAppMessage.prototype.subscribeToClickedEvent InAppMessage.prototype.subscribeToDismissedEvent InAppMessage.fromJson FullScreenMessage ModalMessage HtmlMessage SlideUpMessage User User.Genders User.NotificationSubscriptionTypes User.prototype.addAlias User.prototype.addToCustomAttributeArray User.prototype.addToSubscriptionGroup User.prototype.getUserId User.prototype.incrementCustomUserAttribute User.prototype.removeFromCustomAttributeArray User.prototype.removeFromSubscriptionGroup User.prototype.setCountry User.prototype.setCustomLocationAttribute User.prototype.setCustomUserAttribute User.prototype.setDateOfBirth User.prototype.setEmail User.prototype.setEmailNotificationSubscriptionType User.prototype.setFirstName User.prototype.setGender User.prototype.setHomeCity User.prototype.setLanguage User.prototype.setLastKnownLocation User.prototype.setLastName User.prototype.setPhoneNumber User.prototype.setPushNotificationSubscriptionType InAppMessageButton InAppMessageButton.prototype.removeAllSubscriptions InAppMessageButton.prototype.removeSubscription InAppMessageButton.prototype.subscribeToClickedEvent automaticallyShowInAppMessages destroyFeed hideContentCards showContentCards showFeed showInAppMessage toggleContentCards toggleFeed changeUser destroy getDeviceId initialize isPushBlocked isPushPermissionGranted isPushSupported logCardClick logCardDismissal logCardImpressions logContentCardImpressions logContentCardsDisplayed logCustomEvent logFeedDisplayed logInAppMessageButtonClick logInAppMessageClick logInAppMessageHtmlClick logInAppMessageImpression logPurchase openSession requestPushPermission removeAllSubscriptions removeSubscription requestContentCardsRefresh requestFeedRefresh requestImmediateDataFlush enableSDK isDisabled setLogger setSdkAuthenticationSignature addSdkMetadata disableSDK subscribeToContentCardsUpdates subscribeToFeedUpdates subscribeToInAppMessage subscribeToSdkAuthenticationFailures toggleLogging unregisterPush wipeData handleBrazeAction".split(" "),i=0;i<s.length;i++){for(var m=s[i],k=a.braze,l=m.split("."),j=0;j<l.length-1;j++)k=k[l[j]];k[l[j]]=(new Function("return function "+m.replace(/\./g,"_")+"(){window.brazeQueue.push(arguments); return true}"))()}window.braze.getCachedContentCards=function(){return new window.braze.ContentCards};window.braze.getCachedFeed=function(){return new window.braze.Feed};window.braze.getUser=function(){return new window.braze.User};(y=p.createElement(P)).type='text/javascript';
    y.src='https://js.appboycdn.com/web-sdk/4.2/braze.min.js';
    y.async=1;(b=p.getElementsByTagName(P)[0]).parentNode.insertBefore(y,b)`);
        script.text = code;
        document.head.appendChild(script);
        script.onload = onBrazeSdkLoaded;
```

Comment: Because of limitations etc due to CORS policies etc etc .. I think it would be safer to grab it via CUrl or something of the like in the "back end" and just `echo` it to the front end inside a `<script>` tag ..

Answer (score 0):

A `load` event fires when a resource has been loaded from an external source.

Since your script is getting its program from a text node inside the script element, instead of from a URL assigned to the `src` attribute, there *is no external source*.

Consequently, there is no load event.

If you want `onBrazeSdkLoaded` to fire when the script you create on line 1 has loaded, then just include `onBrazeSdkLoaded()` in the string you assign to `code`.

If you want it to fire when `https://js.appboycdn.com/web-sdk/4.2/braze.min.js` loads, then you need to:

- Ensure it is in the global scope
- Write code that assigns it to `y.onload` inside the string you assign to `code`
- Fix the syntax error(s) in the JS in that string